# Designing a database for tracking location affiliation from multiple sources

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I need a database (not even close to a warehouse yet) that will serve as a master record of office locations and certain attributes associated with them. I have an initial source file, but also will be adding to that information from a number of other supplemental files. Some of the additional information will simply be records I can join to after matching. And some will be information I create once I've validated some status or have some internal knowledge on a location to store.
The source data is mostly flat files - some updated every few months, some annually. I am looking for design advice including ideas for how to query the database later.
I want to be able to start with the records in the initial data source, leave it alone, and then do a number of things in a new database:

- if we verify the address, etc. from the initial source, I want to flag that and be able to give it precedence
- if we can match a record in the initial data source to a record in one of the other data sources, I want to pull one or both records via query
- if a location is participating in a specific program, I want to store that flag, regardless of which source I will keep for the address, etc., i.e. there is information related to a record that is separate from any of the different sources.

So, I was starting to think about something similar to a Star schema, but with a fact table pointing to the separate source tables based on some matching logic. My fact table would have records that include the keys of any of the other sources that are related. And it might also have additional columns for our added info on each record that is separate from the sources.

I was also thinking about just building a table that holds some kind of copy of the current info from each related source - or perhaps a view. But this may not be robust enough to serve as a basic source-of-truth database given all the flags and other additional info I expect to start adding.

This is not a large database - in the tens of thousands only - and does not need high availability to many users/queries. Eventually, I will want to join it to list of individuals at the locations. I'm hoping I can join the people to the places easily after I've got the main locations table built.

I realize this is question has a broad scope. I'm not an experienced database designer and I've searched for advice already but haven't figured out how to describe my challenge so I get relevant search results. All advice and references are most appreciated!

I'm working in SQL Server 2012

Comment: Your requirement looks very close to master data management. Here are a couple of links on the same https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190163.aspx https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_data_management. You can go through them and confirm if your requirements fit in those. If the answer is yes then you can think about using one of the MDM tools for your requirement (why reinvent the wheel?). If licensing and cost is an issue then you might think about building your data model on similar lines of an MDM tool.

Comment: Thanks @phonetic_man. It's definitely an MDM problem. Thanks for the links. My problem is that we are not ready/able to launch such a project yet. We only have one major data source that we are pinning more information to for now, so we need a pre-MDM solution on a small scale for now. I would love to read about examples of pseudo-MDM that people have tried.